# How can I use the self join to find equal values within a group?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am looking to find instances of GROUPID where all price values are 0.  The following is a simplified version of what I am looking at

```
--------------------------------
| Groupid | Price    | Customer|
--------------------------------
| 001     |  9       |  4      |
| 001     |  0       |  4      | 
| 002     |  4       |  4      |
| 002     |  4       |  4      |
| 003     |  0       |  4      |
| 003     |  0       |  4      |
| 004     |  4       |  4      |
| 004     |  7       |  4      |
--------------------------------
```

I am attempting to use the following query to find all GROUPID where both PRICE values for that particular group = 0.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE GROUPID IN
(SELECT TB1.GROUPID FROM MYTABLE TB1 JOIN MYTABLE TB2 ON TB1.GROUPID = TB2.GROUPID
AND TB1.PRICE = 0 AND TB2.PRICE = 0)
and CUSTOMER = 4
ORDER BY GROUPID;
```

This query returns:

```
| Groupid | Price    | Customer|
--------------------------------
| 001     |  9       |  4      |
| 001     |  0       |  4      | 
| 003     |  0       |  4      |
| 003     |  0       |  4      |
--------------------------------
```

In my case, I only need it to return GROUPID 003.

I'd also like to ask for assistance in modifying the query to return all non 0 equal PRICE values within a groupid. It doesn't have to be in the same query as above.  For example the return would be:

```
| Groupid | Price    | Customer|
--------------------------------
| 002     |  4       |  4      |
| 002     |  4       |  4      |
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can the `price` be null?

Comment: Joins are very rarely the right type of answer for this kind of question. GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are the more efficient approach (Gordon posted an answer along these lines.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the prices are zero, then look at the minimum and maximum price for the groupid:

```
select groupid
from mytable t
group by groupid
having min(price) = 0 and max(price) = 0;
```

I should point out that no self-join is required for this.

Comment: Great answer as always. A question please. Which one will be faster on a big table? aggregate or self join or correlated query?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - On any size table, aggregate will be faster than join. Correlated subquery will be even slower than join in many cases (although the optimizer knows that, too, so in simple cases - like this one - it will transform a correlated subquery into a join anyway).

Comment: @mathguy Thanks. I should point out that result of this answer gives only groupid, but OP asked for all the columns. So, an *IN* clause or correlated query is still reqd.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - Oh... I missed that (and oddly the OP accepted the answer even though it didn't answer the question AS ASKED, although that is quite common on SO). The proper way to deal with this, then, is to use analytic functions - a close cousin to aggregate functions.

Comment: I accepted the answer as I put this query as a subquery that selected for all. it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE as m1 where Price = 0
and not exists (
    select 1 
    from MYTABLE as m2 
    where m2.Groupid = m1.Groupid 
    and m2.Price <> 0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list the the rows, whose group_id has no rows with non-zero price

```
select groupid, price, customer from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable where group_id = t.group_id
    and price != 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Gordon's is the best solution for the first part:

```
SELECT groupid
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING (MAX(price) = 0 and MIN(price) = 0)
```

And for the second part:

```
SELECT groupid
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING MIN(price) <> 0 AND (MAX(price) = MIN(price))
```

**My original one:**

```
SELECT groupid
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING SUM(Price) =0
```

This assumes, there are no negative prices.

To the second part of your question:

```
SELECT groupid
FROM mytable t
WHERE Price > 0
GROUP BY GroupID, Price
HAVING COUNT(price) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by counting the number of distinct prices over each group (and I'm assuming that each group will have the same customer) and then filtering on the price(s) you're interested in.

For example, for prices that are 0 for all rows in each groupid+customer:

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT '001' groupid, 9 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '001' groupid, 0 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '002' groupid, 4 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '002' groupid, 4 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '003' groupid, 0 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '003' groupid, 0 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '004' groupid, 4 price, 4 customer FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT '004' groupid, 7 price, 4 customer FROM dual)
SELECT groupid,
       customer,
       price
FROM   (SELECT groupid,
               customer,
               price,
               COUNT(DISTINCT price) OVER (PARTITION BY groupid, customer) num_distinct_prices
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  num_distinct_prices = 1
AND    price = 0;

GROUPID   CUSTOMER      PRICE
------- ---------- ----------
003              4          0
003              4          0
```

Just change the `and price = 0` to `and price != 0` if you want the groups which have the same non-zero price for all rows. Or simply remove that predicate altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data, you have only one customer. I assume if you had more than one customer, you would still want to return the rows where the groupid has the same price, across all rows *and all customers*. If so, you could use the query below. It is almost the same as Boneist's - I just use min(price) and max(price) instead of count(distinct), and I don't include `customer` in `partition by`.

If the price may be NULL, it will be ignored in the computation of max price and min price; if all the NON-NULL prices are equal for a groupid, all the rows for that group will be returned. If price can be NULL and this is NOT the desired behavior, that can be changed easily - but the OP will have to clarify.

The query below retrieves all the cases when there is a single price for the groupid. To retrieve only the groups where the price is 0 (an additional condition), add `and price = 0` to the WHERE clause of the outer query. I added more test data to illustrate some of the cases the query covers.

```
with
     test_data ( groupid, price, customer ) as (
       select '001', 9, 4 from dual union all
       select '001', 0, 4 from dual union all
       select '002', 4, 4 from dual union all
       select '002', 4, 4 from dual union all      
       select '003', 0, 4 from dual union all
       select '003', 0, 4 from dual union all
       select '004', 4, 4 from dual union all      
       select '004', 7, 4 from dual union all
       select '002', 4, 8 from dual union all
       select '005', 2, 8 from dual union all
       select '005', null, 8 from dual
     ),
     prep ( groupid, price, customer, min_price, max_price) as (
       select groupid, price, customer, 
              min(price) over (partition by groupid),
              max(price) over (partition by groupid)
       from   test_data
     )
select groupid, price, customer
from   prep
where  min_price = max_price
;


GROUPID     PRICE  CUSTOMER
------- --------- ---------
002             4         8
002             4         4
002             4         4
003             0         4
003             0         4
005                       8
005             2         8
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE GROUPID NOT IN (
       SELECT GROUPID
         FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE Price <> 0)
```

and just change the last line for the other query:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE GROUPID NOT IN (
       SELECT GROUPID
         FROM MYTABLE
        WHERE Price = 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do it very similarly to what Gordon posted

```
SELECT groupId 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY groupId
HAVING SUM(price) = 0
```